# ionic object change/convert entries

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

i have an object

```js
this.requestData = {
      flightto: 'CGK',
      flightfrom: 'DPS',
      flightdate: '06-04-2018',
      flightpp: 0,
      flightadult: 1
    };
    console.log((<any>Object).entries(this.requestData));
```

if I do console.log () how do I make this object out to be

> flightto=CGK&flightfrom=DPS&flightdate=06-04-2018&flightpp=0&flightadult=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output in a row try this,

```
    let dataString = "";
     Object.keys(this.requestData).forEach(key => {
     dataString+=`${key}=${this.requestData[key]}&`;
    });
    console.log(dataString);
```

or you can do console inside loop

```
    Object.keys(this.requestData).forEach(key => {
      console.log(`${key}=${this.requestData[key]}&`);
     });
```